Is every byte of an executable assigned an address in virtual memory, starting from a base address?
When an executable is started within Linux, how is the entire executable assigned addresses in virtual memory?
I ran "objdump -d bin" and it gave me an output like the following:
11b0    48 83 c4 08     add $0x8,%rsp
11b4    c3              ret

I was wondering how the entire executable file was referenced in memory. After I ran objdump, am I right in assuming that every byte is assigned an address (in virtual memory)? Such as 11b0 = 48, 11b1 = 83, 11b2 = c4, etc?
And if so, do these addresses work based off a "base address" that is given when the file is loaded?
Also, is the base address the same for every program or does it differ? Perhaps if ASLR is active?

I'm not sure what you're asking, because what you're asking depends a lot of your definition of "assign". Obviously, the binary on your disk needs to contain information for every byte on where it is going to go in virtual address space when it's loaded. That information has been worked out by the linker and "assigned". Whether it's loaded at all (and even "sees" the inside of the machine) depends on code coverage and if it's "needed" (could be dead coded and the age would never be mapped to physical memory). If assign means to you "goes to virtual address xxx" the answer differs to if...

... assign means there exists a current mapping between physical and virtual memory, i.e. the respective page is actually loaded. (Note this a assumes a statically-linked, self-contained binary).

Check readelf -a on the binary to show details about the binary, including the program headers which specify the segments that are loaded into memory.

Originally, executables were all loaded at the same base address.  0x401000 on WIndows, for example.  Hackers could use this knowledge to inject fake code through unchecked input routine that overwrote the stack, so these days the base addresses are randomized.

Modern binary module formats specify the memory layout of the module image, usually as a sequence of segments or sections (terminology depends on file type and format). A segment definition usually includes the virtual address and size of the segment, whether it is loaded from the file or zero-filled, and the segment’s memory permissions (read, write, execute).
Some binaries declare support for position independence, meaning that they can be loaded at addresses other than the ones literally specified in the segment definitions. In that case, the OS may choose a new base address (for example, randomizing it for ASLR, or rebasing it to avoid conflicts with other modules), and load all segments relative to that new base address.
Do note that segments do not have to load every byte of the file into memory. Many parts of the file will indeed not be loaded into memory: for example, file headers, debugging information, and other metadata will usually not be referenced by loadable segments, and will therefore not appear in the memory image of the module.
